# Phpmyadmin is showing corrupt images and it is showing icons two times

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am new to php. I have installed phpmyadmin. It was working fine..etc. but recently (or somehow), it is not showing the labels and icons properly. The text is overlapping and unclear
[here is the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHDUc.png)
Can you please suggest me a fix to this?

Comment: How have you installed phpMyAdmin and which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Somehow you seem to be seeing the alternative text that's shown when icon images can't be rendered, but you're also seeing the icons under that text.

Comment: installed using cli in linux server..my phpmyadmin .Version information: 4.9.5deb2

Comment: Any hints in your webserver error log?

Comment: checked already .. still double icons are there in the phpmyadmin as shown in the pic attacked in the original question posted. already searched a lot over net and it seems it's a unique problem happening only with me ..

Comment: apt-get update ....apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin    . Reinstalling phpmyadmin is also not clearing the icons.

Answer (score 0):

finally sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin* worked.. The asterisk sign in the end was the key..earlier I was trying it without the asterisk , hope this can save time if anybody gets into this type of trouble.